# if element hasClass then change background file

Tags: javascript, jquery

hi i need to write if statement which checking if span has class "nie" and if so it should changed background file but my statement setting every where first bg file "bg-nie.png", what is wrong ?

jQuery code

```
if ($(".rzuty span.mieszkanie").hasClass("nie")) {
        $(".rzuty span.mieszkanie").css("background", "url(img/rzuty/mieszkania/bg-nie.png) repeat");
    } else {
        $(".rzuty span.mieszkanie").css("background", "url(img/rzuty/mieszkania/bg-tak.png) repeat");
    }
```

HTML

```
<div id="rzuty07p" class="rzuty">
    <span id="c_07_226" class="mieszkanie" title=""></span>
    <span id="c_07_228" class="mieszkanie" title=""></span>
    <span id="c_07_227a" class="mieszkanie" title=""></span>
    <span id="c_07_227b" class="mieszkanie" title=""></span>
    <span id="c_07_229" class="mieszkanie nie" title=""></span>
    <span id="c_07_005" class="mieszkanie" title=""></span>
    <span id="c_07_006" class="mieszkanie" title=""></span>
    <span id="c_07_008" class="mieszkanie" title=""></span>
    <span id="c_07_007a" class="mieszkanie nie" title=""></span>
    <span id="c_07_007b" class="mieszkanie nie" title=""></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be simplified to not require an if statement. Just filter your selection further:

```
var $rzutyspan = $(".rzuty span.mieszkanie");
$rzutyspan.filter(".nie").css("background", "url(img/rzuty/mieszkania/bg-nie.png) repeat");
$rzutyspan.not(".nie").css("background", "url(img/rzuty/mieszkania/bg-tak.png) repeat");
```

See Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/4A4W7/

---

Alternatively, this can be achieved with plain CSS:

```
.rzuty span.mieszkanie
{
   background: url(img/rzuty/mieszkania/bg-tak.png) repeat;
}
.rzuty span.mieszkanie.nie
{
   background: url(img/rzuty/mieszkania/bg-nie.png) repeat;
}
```

Comment: is it faster then if statement ??

Comment: @gidzior Yes, as your if statement won't work correctly as it is. You'd have to introduce a loop (as Starx has answered)

Comment: plain CSS this is the answer, what was i thinking :], thx mate

Comment: @gidzior, Its definitely faster than the solution I posted as this one selects elements as per the condition and manipulates them.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you are using a common class `.mieszkanie` to check and manipulate all the set that matches. Check and manipulate separately:

```
$(".rzuty span.mieszkanie").each(function(k,v) {
    if ($(this).hasClass("nie")) {
        $(this).css("background", "url(img/rzuty/mieszkania/bg-nie.png) repeat");
    } else {
        $(this).css("background", "url(img/rzuty/mieszkania/bg-tak.png) repeat");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it:
http://jsfiddle.net/xoreznik/kC5L2/

You're using an if statement on a selector which in this case will return multiple objects.
In the attached fiddle you can see how to target any element that has/doesn't have the target class and apply css to it.